# Qt5 cmake cannot find header file of ui

Tags: cmake, qt5

I'm creating a cmake project of my Qt5 application. Now when I compile my application using cmake in Clion I got a fatal error.

My CMakeLists.txt file looks like:

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

project(Oefening11_kv)

# Find includes in corresponding build directories
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
# Instruct CMake to run moc automatically when needed.
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

set (CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH C:\\Qt\\Qt5.8.0\\5.8\\mingw53_32\\lib\\cmake\\)

# Find the Qt libraries
find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Widgets)
find_package(Qt5Gui)
find_package(Qt5Charts)

set(Oefening11_kv_SOURCES main.cpp oefening11a.cpp oefening11b.cpp oefening11c.cpp)
set(Oefening11_kv_HEADERS oefening11a.h oefening11b.h oefening11c.h)
set(Oefening11_kv_FORMS oefening11a.ui)

QT5_WRAP_CPP(Oefening11_kv_HEADERS_MOC ${Oefening11_kv_HEADERS})
QT5_WRAP_UI(Oefening11_kv_FORMS_HEADERS ${Oefening11_kv_FORMS})

add_library(Oefening11_kv_CONFIG ${Oefening11_kv_HEADERS_MOC} ${Oefening11_kv_FORMS_HEADERS})
QT5_USE_MODULES(Oefening11_kv_CONFIG Widgets)

add_executable(Oefening11_kv ${Oefening11_kv_SOURCES} ${Oefening11_kv_CONFIG})
QT5_USE_MODULES(Oefening11_kv Core Gui Widgets Charts)
```

The error that Clion is trowing when I compile the application is:

> > oefening11a.cpp:21: undefined reference to
> >     `__imp__ZN8QtCharts11QLineSeriesC1EP7QObject' oefening11a.cpp:26:
> >     undefined reference to`__imp__ZN8QtCharts9QXYSeries6appendEdd'
> >     oefening11a.cpp:30: undefined reference to
> >     `__imp__ZN8QtCharts6QChartC1EP13QGraphicsItem6QFlagsIN2Qt10WindowTypeEE' oefening11a.cpp:31: undefined reference to`
> >     __imp__ZN8QtCharts6QChart9addSeriesEPNS_15QAbstractSeriesE'
> >     oefening11a.cpp:32: undefined reference to
> >     `__imp__ZNK8QtCharts6QChart6legendEv' oefening11a.cpp:33: undefined
> >     reference to`__imp__ZN8QtCharts6QChart8setTitleERK7QString'
> >     oefening11a.cpp:36: undefined reference to
> >     `__imp__ZN8QtCharts10QValueAxisC1EP7QObject' oefening11a.cpp:37:
> >     undefined reference to`
> >     __imp__ZN8QtCharts10QValueAxis14setLabelFormatERK7QString'
> >     oefening11a.cpp:38: undefined reference to
> >     `__imp__ZN8QtCharts13QAbstractAxis12setTitleTextERK7QString'
> >     oefening11a.cpp:39: undefined reference to`
> >     __imp__ZN8QtCharts6QChart7addAxisEPNS_13QAbstractAxisE6QFlagsIN2Qt13AlignmentFlagEE'
> >     oefening11a.cpp:40: undefined reference to
> >     `__imp__ZN8QtCharts15QAbstractSeries10attachAxisEPNS_13QAbstractAxisE'
> >     oefening11a.cpp:43: undefined reference to`
> >     __imp__ZN8QtCharts10QValueAxisC1EP7QObject' oefening11a.cpp:44:
> >     undefined reference to
> >     `__imp__ZN8QtCharts10QValueAxis14setLabelFormatERK7QString'
> >     oefening11a.cpp:45: undefined reference to`
> >     __imp__ZN8QtCharts13QAbstractAxis12setTitleTextERK7QString'
> >     oefening11a.cpp:46: undefined reference to
> >     `__imp__ZN8QtCharts6QChart7addAxisEPNS_13QAbstractAxisE6QFlagsIN2Qt13AlignmentFlagEE'
> >     oefening11a.cpp:47: undefined reference to`
> >     __imp__ZN8QtCharts15QAbstractSeries10attachAxisEPNS_13QAbstractAxisE'
> >     oefening11a.cpp:50: undefined reference to
> >     `__imp__ZN8QtCharts10QChartViewC1EPNS_6QChartEP7QWidget'
> >     oefening11a.cpp:51: undefined reference to`
> >     __imp__ZN13QGraphicsView13setRenderHintEN8QPainter10RenderHintEb'
> >     oefening11a.cpp:54: undefined reference to
> >     `__imp__ZN11QMainWindow16setCentralWidgetEP7QWidget'
> >     oefening11a.cpp:73: undefined reference to`
> >     __imp__ZN10QStatusBar11showMessageERK7QStringi' t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0x38):
> >     undefined reference to `QMainWindow::event(QEvent*)'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0x40):
> >     undefined reference to`QObject::eventFilter(QObject*, QEvent*)'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0x48):
> >     undefined reference to `QObject::timerEvent(QTimerEvent*)'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0x50):
> >     undefined reference to`QObject::childEvent(QChildEvent*)'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0x58):
> >     undefined reference to `QObject::customEvent(QEvent*)'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0x60):
> >     undefined reference to`QObject::connectNotify(QMetaMethod const&)'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0x68):
> >     undefined reference to `QObject::disconnectNotify(QMetaMethod const&)'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0x70):
> >     undefined reference to`QWidget::devType() const'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0x78):
> >     undefined reference to `QWidget::setVisible(bool)'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0x80):
> >     undefined reference to`QWidget::sizeHint() const'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0x88):
> >     undefined reference to `QWidget::minimumSizeHint() const'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0x90):
> >     undefined reference to`QWidget::heightForWidth(int) const'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0x98):
> >     undefined reference to `QWidget::hasHeightForWidth() const'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0xa0):
> >     undefined reference to`QWidget::paintEngine() const'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0xa8):
> >     undefined reference to `QWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent*)'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0xb0):
> >     undefined reference to`QWidget::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent*)'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0xb8):
> >     undefined reference to `QWidget::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent*)'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0xc0):
> >     undefined reference to`QWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent*)'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0xc8):
> >     undefined reference to `QWidget::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent*)'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0xd0):
> >     undefined reference to`QWidget::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent*)'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0xd8):
> >     undefined reference to `QWidget::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent*)'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0xe0):
> >     undefined reference to`QWidget::focusInEvent(QFocusEvent*)'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0xe8):
> >     undefined reference to `QWidget::focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent*)'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0xf0):
> >     undefined reference to`QWidget::enterEvent(QEvent*)'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0xf8):
> >     undefined reference to `QWidget::leaveEvent(QEvent*)'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0x100):
> >     undefined reference to`QWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0x108):
> >     undefined reference to `QWidget::moveEvent(QMoveEvent*)'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0x110):
> >     undefined reference to`QWidget::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent*)'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0x118):
> >     undefined reference to `QWidget::closeEvent(QCloseEvent*)'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0x120):
> >     undefined reference to`
> >     QMainWindow::contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent*)'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0x128):
> >     undefined reference to `QWidget::tabletEvent(QTabletEvent*)'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0x130):
> >     undefined reference to`QWidget::actionEvent(QActionEvent*)'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0x138):
> >     undefined reference to `QWidget::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent*)'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0x140):
> >     undefined reference to`QWidget::dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent*)'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0x148):
> >     undefined reference to `QWidget::dragLeaveEvent(QDragLeaveEvent*)'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0x150):
> >     undefined reference to`QWidget::dropEvent(QDropEvent*)'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0x158):
> >     undefined reference to `QWidget::showEvent(QShowEvent*)'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0x160):
> >     undefined reference to`QWidget::hideEvent(QHideEvent*)'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0x168):
> >     undefined reference to `QWidget::nativeEvent(QByteArray const&, void*,
> >     long*)'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0x170):
> >     undefined reference to`QWidget::changeEvent(QEvent*)'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0x178):
> >     undefined reference to
> >     `QWidget::metric(QPaintDevice::PaintDeviceMetric) const'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0x180):
> >     undefined reference to`QWidget::initPainter(QPainter*) const'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0x188):
> >     undefined reference to `QWidget::redirected(QPoint*) const'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0x190):
> >     undefined reference to`QWidget::sharedPainter() const'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0x198):
> >     undefined reference to `QWidget::inputMethodEvent(QInputMethodEvent*)'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0x1a0):
> >     undefined reference to`
> >     QWidget::inputMethodQuery(Qt::InputMethodQuery) const'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0x1a8):
> >     undefined reference to `QWidget::focusNextPrevChild(bool)'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0x1b0):
> >     undefined reference to`QMainWindow::createPopupMenu()'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0x1d8):
> >     undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to QWidget::devType() const'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0x1e0):
> >     undefined reference to`non-virtual thunk to QWidget::paintEngine()
> >     const'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0x1e8):
> >     undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to
> >     QWidget::metric(QPaintDevice::PaintDeviceMetric) const'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0x1f0):
> >     undefined reference to`non-virtual thunk to
> >     QWidget::initPainter(QPainter*) const'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0x1f8):
> >     undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to
> >     QWidget::redirected(QPoint*) const'
> >     t_automoc.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV11Oefening11A[_ZTV11Oefening11A]+0x200):
> >     undefined reference to`non-virtual thunk to QWidget::sharedPainter()
> >     const'

Can't find the problem in my cmake file. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found the issue. I was using a x64 compiler on x86 QT5 libraries. When changing the compiler to a x86 one it compiles.

Answer (score 0):

Besides `moc`, you will need to run `uic` as well:

```
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
```

Comment: When I add this, I got allot of undefined reference to errors.